# Javascript looping code returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to create a function (called difference) which will find the difference between the sum of an array of numbers, and (its maximum value * number of items in the array). I have tried the following, but it keeps returning undefined! Any help?

```
function difference(randomArray){

  var origSum = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++ ) {
      sum += randomArray[i]
    };
    return sum;  
  };

  var maxi = function () {  
    var max = 0
    for (var x = 0; x < randomArray.length; x++) {
      if (randomArray[x] > max) {
        max = randomArray[x]
      };
    };
    return max;
  };

  var sum = function () {
    return ((maxi * randomArray.length) - origSum)
  };

  if (randomArray.length <= 1) {
    return (1 - 2)
  } 
  else {
    return sum
  };
};
```

Comment: For max of an array see [how to use Math.max.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sum` function, you are trying to multiply a function by another function, you have to actually call the functions, as well as calling the `sum` function at the end of your script:

```
var sum = function () {
    return ((maxi() * randomArray.length) - origSum())
};
```

And:

```
return sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

maxi, origSum and sum are functions. You need to call them like that, including parentheses.

```
function difference(randomArray){

  var origSum = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++ ) {
      sum += randomArray[i]
    };
    return sum;  
  };

  var maxi = function () {  
    var max = 0; // What if all array values are negative? 
    for (var x = 0; x < randomArray.length; x++) {
      if (randomArray[x] > max) {
        max = randomArray[x]
      };
    };
    return max;
  };

  var sum = function () {
    return ((maxi() * randomArray.length) - origSum())  // < here
  };

  if (randomArray.length <= 1) {
    return (1 - 2)  // This is weird ?
  } 
  else {
    return sum(); // < and here
  };
};
```

There are some shortcomings by the way. maxi will return 0 instead of the greatest value if all the values in the array are negative. And at the end, `return (1 - 2)` always return -1, while you probably want to return the one and only array value if the array contains 1 item.

Comment: Thanks very much! As per the fine details, I'm working on one of those coding practice sites where they give you obscure tasks, so I am aware some of the code is a bit weird but they had some odd requirements.